# How to use flask-cache on a route with parameter

Tags: python, flask, flask-cache

I have a flask app that retrieves data from a database. I would like to cache this data so I am not constantly requesting data from the database.

Currently I am using `flask_caching` and it is working, but ONLY for the individual document I request.

For example the database might contain 1000 rows, and I would like to cache ALL rows (not just one row, which is the behaviour now). I understand it is doing this, because the URL I am requesting specifies the doc_id.

My route in flask looks like this:

```
@site.route('/display/<doc_id>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@cache.cached(query_string=True)
def display(doc_id):
    results = connect_to_db_get_ALL_results()
    return render_template("display.html")
```

The above code is simplified. I can see the cache IS working for a specific document (ie if I load the page **http://localhost/display/1** , then click on the "Next" button on my rendered page to retrieve the next document (**http://localhost/display/2**), it will retrieve it from the database (not the cache), but it will cache what it just received from the database because when I click "previous document" on the rendered page (**http://localhost/display/1**), it will retrieve it from the cache.

Because my function "connect_to_db_get_ALL_results" actually returns all of the results I need for all docs..  What I would like to do is cache all of these documents (rather than just the current document in the URL). Such that if I decided to load **http://localhost/display/994** it would select the data from the cache.

I have tried a few things (including using `query_string` and `memoize`, but neither of these things is what I need), I have also tried caching the function that returns ALL of the results, but this doesn't seem to work. Please help!

UPDATE:
The way around this was to cache the function (that returns all results) rather than the route.

```
@site.route('/display/<doc_id>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def display(doc_id):
    results = connect_to_db_get_ALL_results()
    return render_template("display.html")

@cache.cached(timeout=500, key_prefix='all_docs')
def connect_to_db_get_ALL_results()
    <code to fetch the data from the table>
```

Comment: Do you want to cache the routes before they have ever been called? I am not sure if that's what you're trying to achieve. Normally, they would be cached after they have been called at least once...

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 thanks for the reply/question. Yes, that's what I am trying to do, let me update my question to make it clearer.

Comment: I dont think that's possible, or at least not out of the box - a cache is generated after the first time it is used, it remembers the return value from the previous time. there is no previous time at the first time, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

The way around this was to cache the function (that returns all results) rather than the route.

```
@site.route('/display/<doc_id>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def display(doc_id):
    results = connect_to_db_get_ALL_results()
    return render_template("display.html")

@cache.cached(timeout=500, key_prefix='all_docs')
def connect_to_db_get_ALL_results()
    <code to fetch the data from the table>
```

Comment: but if the endpoint is parameterised, the function returning the data also will need parameters, in this case, the doc_id, so your example doesn't make sense.